# SMTP gmx server problam

Tags: smtp

Im tyring to send an email with my program to an gmx email. Every time I try to send the mail I get the same error message in my console.
What can be the solution for that?
The error message:
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: SMTP server requiers secure connection or the client wasnt authenticated. server response was: authentication required.
in - System.Net.Mail.SendMailAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
in - System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SMTP_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool mailSent = false;
        private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender,         AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
            String token = (string)e.UserState;

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
        }
        mailSent = true;
    }   
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmx.com",25);
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("example@project.com", "me " + (char)0xD8 + " you", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("example@gmx.com");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Body = "The project has succeeded ";
        message.Subject = "made it!";

        client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

        string userState = "test message2\n";
        client.SendAsync(message, userState);
        Console.WriteLine("Sending message... press c to cancel mail. Press any other key to exit.");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer.StartsWith("c") && mailSent == false)
        {
            client.SendAsyncCancel();
        }
        message.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("proccess ended.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: your "gmx"  SMTP Server  says whats wrong directly in the error message if you bothered to read it.  `SMTP server requiers secure connection`

Comment: port 25 is not a secure connnection.

Comment: I've read it... But every port that I try returns me the same error

Comment: Well, the issue is that you need to use some form of encryption in order to securely transfer via SMTP  - I would recommend looking into  starttls and other forms of secure data transfer and researching how to use those methods instead of plain text transfer (plain text transfer will be completely phased out from the entire internet in the not-so-distance future)